# A commutative ring with group of invertible elements isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ has characteristic 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Denote by $R^*$ the group of invertible elements (this is a group w.r.t multiplication.) Suppose $R^*\cong  \mathbb{Z}$. I need to show that $1+1=0$ in $R$.

I have no clue about why such statement should be true. I don't even have an example for a ring that satisfies these assumptions, so I'd be glad to see one.

Hints (or partial solutions) will be welcomed.
Thank you!

Comment: Others have already given the answers. It might be instructive to know some near-misses. Take the ring $\{a+b\sqrt2\mid a,b\in\mathbf{Z}\}$. The unit group is almost $\mathbf{Z}$. It is a direct product of $\mathbf{Z}$ with a group of order 2. The torsion group is generated by $-1$ and the *free part* is generated by $3+2\sqrt2$, called a *fundamental unit*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hint 1:* $-1$ is a unit and so is a power of $u$, where $u$ is a generator of $R^\times$.

*Hint 2:*
$(-1)^2=1$. What are  the elements of finite order in $\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you. $-1=u^a$ so $1=u^{2a}$ and therefore $a=0$.
Do you have an example for such ring?

Comment: $\mathbb F_2[X,X^{-1}]$

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* If $R^{\times}\cong{\mathbb Z}$, then in particular it has no nontrivial torsion; on the other hand, there's $-1\in R^{\times}$.

Comment: I don't know what a torsion of a ring is...

Comment: @35T41 An element $x\in A$ in an abelian group $A$ is torsion if there is some $n>0$ such that $na=0$. In the case of $R^{\times}$, it coincides with roots of unity / elements of finite order. Anyways, after lhf has edited his answer (+1), my hint is the same as his second one.

Comment: @35T41 Also note that Hanno did just mean the torsion of the **group** $R^*$.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I did hear about torsions of groups before